# ServiceLayer Exception not been catched on controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

Testing my application I decided to shutdown the database.

```
public Object getEntityById(Class<?> clazz, Object _id) throws PersistenceServiceException {
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o = entityManager.find(clazz, _id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PersistenceServiceException(e);
    }
    return o;
}
```

so, **any database exception should be passed to the caller**.

and in the controller I have

```
    try {
        template = (Template)persistenceService.getEntityById(Template.class, id);
    } catch (PersistenceServiceException e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.setStatusMessage("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR");
        response.setData(e);
        return  response;
    }
```

**when debugging, I can see the DatabaseException been throw.**

but in servlet-context, once I have this...

```
<beans:bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultErrorView" value="core/error.uncatched" />
</beans:bean>
```

it keeps treating the above error as unhandled.

How can I catch it on the controller? Why is it happening?

**The Exception**

```
ERROR: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - **Application exception overridden by commit exception**
com.company.exceptions.PersistenceServiceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20130619-7d05127): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: This problem occurs for not finding mysql database path properly. Can you put your mysql connection code?

Comment: The database is off as I said. The real problem is how to catch it into the controller. The why here is, why it's not catching it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PersistenceException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html) to catch exception .Because you are using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

The true is that the Transactional context is throwing a TransactionSystemException (a RunTimeException), so the wrapped excetion I did is been wrapper again by the TransactionSystemException. This last one need to be added to the catch clause in the controller.

Anyway I not mark it as correct right now. If somebody wants to add something, is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace shows these two exceptions:

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

It means that the database is not reachable. Which is because you have shutdown the database. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) is a discussion about this exception.

> ERROR: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - **Application exception overridden by commit exception**

The default configuration of Spring framework's transaction infrastructure marks a transaction for rollback only when the thrown Exception is an unchecked exception. If you have defined the `PersistenceServiceException` as a checked exception, it will not cause rollback in Spring transaction. You are catching an unchecked exception (in your `getEntityById` method), converting it to a checked exception and then you are throwing this checked exception.

To solve this you can configure the transaction infrastructure to rollback the transaction for `PersistenceServiceException` by

> Changing the `PersistenceServiceException` into a runtime exception (PersistenceServiceException extends RuntimeException)

or by annotating your service with

> @Transactional(rollbackFor = PersistenceServiceException.class)